# How to access from main activity to custom made activity without using any views

Tags: android

Q 1. What should I use to access from main_activity to custom_view activity?

Q 2. Is there any relation between a layout and the click event?

Q 3. Do I need to write setContentView in MyView constructor?

**MainActivity**

```
    package com.easyway2win;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        //Button bpink;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyView.class); 
            startActivity(intent);

    }

    }
```

**MyView**

```
    package com.easyway2win;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class MyView extends View implements OnClickListener{

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        bpink = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pinkColor);
        bpink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Hi","Hello");
            }
        });
```

**myview_activity.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mytxtId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mytext" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pinkColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/mytxtId"
            android:background="@drawable/pinkcolor"
            android:text="Submit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blueColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/mytxtId"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pinkColor"
            android:background="@drawable/bluecolor" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    bpink = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pinkColor);
    bpink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Hi","Hello");
        }
    });
```

the code above should be moved from Constructor to `onCreate` in `MyView`

also you have to add `setContentView(R.layout.myview_activity);`, the final result should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myview_activity);
        bpink = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pinkColor);
        bpink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Hi","Hello");
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A1. you can use intent to access another activity. 
A2. When you create an activity then it must have a layout file and you want to refer it in onCreate() method using setContentView. 
A3. You want to write setContentView in onCreate method, also the button click and reference. because you are refer a button in your custom view, So before that you must set a layout for that activity and then refer the elements from that layout.

Comment: First Error is  @Override : remove from onCreate in myview_activity and second error is onCreate method is undefined. I am taking              MyView extends View. I have removed Activity from MyView. and third error It is prompting me for adding constructor MyView. Please, help me

Comment: Change yiur code to MyView extends Activity. Then implements onCreate()

Comment: My Program need to use View. Please, could you modify my program. Thanks

Comment: Please, some one can help me to find out the problem.  Thank you

Comment: If you want to use views then refer http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html.